# Why doesn't the advanced MATE menu have Education?

Tags: ubuntu-mate, anki

So I just installed Anki (the flashcard program) via the command line but I realised it doesn't come up on my MATE menu (advanced).

I then realised that Anki belongs to the Education category, but the advanced MATE menu is missing the Education category, is this by design? If so, how do I add it? If not, should I report this so they can update this accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be the default choice. Right click on MATE menu and click `Edit menu`. Then check the `Education` box in column `Show` under `Items`. Finally, logout and login so that changes can take effect.

Comment: I'm using the Advanced Menu (Education is ticked already). You can enable this through MATE tweak -> Interface -> Panel Features -> Enable advanced menu.

Comment: @Phil I just installed `anki` and with the `Education` menu checked it is shown ok, I just needed to logout and login again in order to refresh. Try again at `Edit menu` and choose the `Education` entry under `Menus` and see if `Anki` is unchecked.

Comment: You're right, I had to relog for it to work (someone told me incorrectly that I didn't need to relog)